# secure WCF restful service with aspnet membership and roles

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have an asp.net application which uses aspnet mebeership and roles for authentication. I want to create a WCF RESTFul service that uses same thing. I want this service to use same users database and authenticate the users. How can I do this. Also, I want this service to be secure so that only authenticated users can access it.

Please suggest.

Thanks